# Initiating wow.js inside of WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, integration

I have found a tutorial on initializing the wow.js inside of WordPress but struggling to get it to work. Can anyone please advise?

I have added the following to functions.php:

```
//* Enqueue Animate.CSS and WOW.js
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sk_enqueue_scripts' );
function sk_enqueue_scripts() {

    if ( is_home() || is_archive() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.min.css' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'wow', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/wow.min.js', array(), '', true );
    }

}

//* Enqueue script to activate WOW.js
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sk_wow_init_in_footer');
function sk_wow_init_in_footer() {

    if ( is_home() || is_archive() ) {
        add_action( 'print_footer_scripts', 'wow_init' );
    }

}
```

When viewing page source on webpage, the links work correctly. The bit I'm struggling with is when adding:

```
//* Add JavaScript before </body>
function wow_init() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new WOW().init();
    </script>
<?php }
```

Am I missing some tags? my script (footer.php):

```
<div id="footer">&copy;<?php echo date("Y"); echo " "; bloginfo('name'); ?></div>

    </div>

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>


function wow_init() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new WOW().init();
    </script>
<?php }
</body>
```

Thanks for looking. [Tutorial webpage link](https://gist.github.com/srikat/11533776)

Comment: are you able to see new WOW().init(); code in view source?
that function wow_init() should be in functions.php not in footer.php

Comment: Thanks, I was putting the code in the wrong location. High Five!